# Cancel drop event after catch element with mouse click

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having trouble canceling a drop event. Anyway, I catch the item, and after leaving the area I want to cancel the event and release the item right away. I try this way but it doesn't work:

```
onDragLeave(event) {
  const className = event.target.className;

  if (className === 'main-container')
  {
    const container = document.querySelector('.main-container');
    const dragEndEvent = new Event('dragend', { bubbles: true });
    container.dispatchEvent(dragEndEvent);

  }
}
```

Function onDragLeave is in html (dragleave) and after I leave container area I want cancel event immediately.Is this done somehow?